# Can Kerberos service tickets be granted by the KDC (in Active Directory) also on the basis of user authorization?

Tags: windows, active-directory, kerberos, cifs

I am trying to understand better how Kerberos is integrated in Active Directory but I couldn't find a clear answer to this question from the Microsoft documentation.
I understand the process of getting a service ticket to a service from the KDC: client presents his TGT to the KDC along with a request to a specific service, the KDC will send back a service ticket to the client and the client uses this service ticket when accessing the service.

My question is: can I configure the KDC (Active Directory) to refuse to grant a service ticket to specific services for specific users/groups ?

I've tried to search the web for this and play around with configurations in order to achieve this, but I am beginning to suspect that the service ticket only role is to tell the service that "this user is indeed from the legitimate domain" and therefore a service ticket can be given to anyone on the domain. So for example in the case of CIFS (file server) even if I remove all shares from a computer, I can still see that every user can see this computer (i.e via \computer) and by running "klist tickets" I also see that they are granted a ticket to the CIFS service for "computer" even when they can't see any shared folder or drive on it. So specifically in this example, can I somehow make it so that a specific user will never be given a "CIFS" type service ticket for this computer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with Kerberos. It has been designed for authentication only. You wan't authorization. This is a different problem area.

Answer (score 0):

This is non-trivial to setup but with Windows Server 2012 R2 AD, this is possible to do. Take a look at Authentication Policies & Siloes - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn486813.aspx